# Regex to ensure that in a string such as "05123:12315", the first number is less than the second?

Tags: c#, regex

I must have strings in the format ***x:y*** where *x* and *y* have to be five digits (zero padded) and *x* <= *y*.

Example:

```
00515:02152
```

What Regex will match this format?

If possible, please explain the solution briefly to help me learn.

**EDIT:** Why do I need Regex? I've written a generic tool that takes input and validates it according to a configuration file. An unexpected requirement popped up that would require me to validate a string in the format I've shown (using the configuration file). I was hoping to solve this problem using the existing configuration framework I've coded up, as splitting and parsing would be out of the scope of this tool. For an outstanding requirement such as this, I don't mind having some unorthodox/messy regex, as long as it's not 10000 lines long. Any *intelligent* solutions using Regex are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Are Regex a required technology? Can't you use something else?

Comment: Regex would not be a good solution for this problem.

Comment: You can write anything as a regex, but usually that regex is insanely complex. This is especially the case when you want to assign meaning to the matches.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. You're working in C#, so there should be no need to do so. Use `string.Split` to split on the `:` character, then use `int.Parse`.

Comment: @MSalters: You cannot write *anything* as a regexp; for example, the pattern "some number of X followed by some number of Y followed by some number of Z such that the number of X squared plus the number of Y squared is equal to the number of Z squared" *cannot* be recognized by a regular expression.  However, any language that has a *finite* number of elements can be recognized by a regular expression. Since the stated language is finite, there is a regular expression for it, but you are right that it is insanely complicated in this particular case.

Comment: I've written a generic tool that takes input and validates it according to a configuration file. An unexpected requirement popped up that would require me to validate a string in the format I've shown. I was hoping to solve this problem using the existing framework I've coded up, as splitting and parsing would be out of the scope of this tool. As most of you have shown, regex probably isn't the tool for the job. Still, for an outstanding requirement such as this, I'd like to fit into my framework. So, any intelligent solutions using regex are appreciated!

Comment: @br1, thank you for asking me a QUESTION rather than assuming another solution is available to me. Much appreciated!

Comment: It's obvious you don't want to hear this, but you're going about this the wrong way. Denomales' answer, while cool, will almost certainly be slower than the method of integer parsing that numerous people have recommended. If the design of your tool does not allow you to include arbitrary validation code, you need to rethink your design, as there's always the possibility you'll need to do additional, more complex validation in the future.

Comment: @MgSam, without understanding the full picture, I don't think it's a great idea to make _assertions_ about people's projects or code. Sometimes there are valid reasons for approaching a problem a particular way that cannot be grasped by a cursory understanding of the situation or the project requirements. I asked this question with the tool's purpose, _scope_, and requirements in mind. I liked br1's comment because he humbly gave me the benefit of the doubt with a clear intent to help. Comments suggesting alternatives _after_ I've clarified I want to use regex are not too productive I feel.

Comment: @Dalal I recognize you may have requirements that you or a 3rd party (a superior even) may have set. However, using tools for that which they were not designed is a slippery slope to get into. You vastly increase the probability of a maintenance nightmare in the future when you or someone else needs to add/change features to this code.

Comment: @MgSam, you're right about that. In my case, it's less about the code and more about how to write the configuration file for it. My code exposes configuration properties that help with validation which contain regex attributes.  It's intended to be used in a certain way (regex validation). However, a certain group would like to use it differently, and so in struggling to keep the tool generic, I decided to try to fit their requirements into the config file without having to change the program code. This is a one-time deal just to satisfy them. I'm not touching my program code, just the config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Description

This expression will validate that the first 5 digit number is smaller then the second 5 digit number where zero padded 5 digit numbers are in a `:` delimited string and is formatted as `01234:23456`.

```
^
(?:
(?=0....:[1-9]|1....:[2-9]|2....:[3-9]|3....:[4-9]|4....:[5-9]|5....:[6-9]|6....:[7-9]|7....:[8-9]|8....:[9])
|(?=(.)(?:0...:\1[1-9]|1...:\1[2-9]|2...:\1[3-9]|3...:\1[4-9]|4...:\1[5-9]|5...:\1[6-9]|6...:\1[7-9]|7...:\1[8-9]|8...:\1[9]))
|(?=(..)(?:0..:\2[1-9]|1..:\2[2-9]|2..:\2[3-9]|3..:\2[4-9]|4..:\2[5-9]|5..:\2[6-9]|6..:\2[7-9]|7..:\2[8-9]|8..:\2[9]))
|(?=(...)(?:0.:\3[1-9]|1.:\3[2-9]|2.:\3[3-9]|3.:\3[4-9]|4.:\3[5-9]|5.:\3[6-9]|6.:\3[7-9]|7.:\3[8-9]|8.:\3[9]))
|(?=(....)(?:0:\4[1-9]|1:\4[2-9]|2:\4[3-9]|3:\4[4-9]|4:\4[5-9]|5:\4[6-9]|6:\4[7-9]|7:\4[8-9]|8:\4[9]))
)
\d{5}:\d{5}$
```

Live demo:  http://www.rubular.com/r/w1QLZhNoEa

Note that this is using the `x` option to ignore all white space and allow comments, if you use this without `x` then the expression will need to be all on one line

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you saw this as a challenge, but you really have wasted a chunk of your day.

Comment: Meh, it was an interesting 15 minute challenge.

Comment: It wasn't wasted! Thank you Denomales for answering my question. This is exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for.

Comment: +1 for your rather impressive regex foo. It always impresses/terrifies me people can do with regex.

Comment: Wow, we have a Regex Rider :) probably it would take me more than 15 minutes to understand your solution

Comment: What tool did you use to produce the picture?

Answer (score 5):

The language you want to recognize is *finite*, so the easiest thing to do is just list all the cases separated by "or". The regexp you want is:

```
(00000:[00000|00001| ... 99999])|  ...  |(99998:[99998|99999])|(99999:99999)
```

That regexp will be several billion characters long and take quite some time to execute, but it is what you asked for: a regular expression that matches the stated language.

Obviously that's impractical. Now is it clear why regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job? Use a regular expression to match 5 digits - colon - five digits, and then once you know you have that, split up the string and convert the two sets of digits to *integers* that you can compare.

Comment: Using this method you will have 5,000,049,999 5 digit numbers listed out.  (Here you have a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) going up to 100,000 (minus one).

Comment: Or you could just write a regex that evaluates the digits in each position and adheres to the rules which govern why a number is larger then the other.

Comment: @Denomales: Indeed, you give a good example of such. My point is twofold: (1) any finite language is regular, but that's doesn't mean that the regexp is convenient, and (2) some tasks that are very simple outside of a regular expression -- such as comparing two integers -- are complicated to do in a regular expression. Your example illustrates this latter point quite well.

Comment: My 600 character example shows how it can be done without the most complex solution of listing all 5 billion combinations ;) . I do agree that somethings are best handled by other methods which are better suited to the task. However writing something off as "use a better tool because this one is impractical" is only helpful if the recommended tool is an available option.

Answer (score 2):

> x <= y.

Well, you are using wrong tool. Really, regex can't help you here. Or even if you get a solution, that will be too complex, and will be too difficult to expand.

Regex is a text-processing tool to match pattern in regular languages. It is *very weak* when it comes to ***semantics***. It cannot identify *meaning* in the given string. Like in your given condition, to conform to `x <= y` condition, you need to have the knowledge of their numerical values.

*For e.g.*, it can match digits in a sequence, or a mix of digits and characters, but **what it cannot do** is the stuff like -

- *match a number greater than `15` and less than `1245`*, or
- *match a pattern which is a date between given two dates*.

So, where-ever matching a pattern, involves applying *semantics* to the matched string, Regex is not an option there.

The appropriate way here would be to `split` the string on `colon`, and then compare numbers. For leading zero, you can find some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generally* do this with regex. You can use regex to match the pattern and extract the numbers, then compare the numbers in your code.

For example to match such format (without comparing the numbers) and get the numbers you could use:

```
^(\d{5}):(\d{5})\z
```

*) You probably could in this case (as the numbers are always 5 digits and zero padded, but it wouldn't be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this instead:

```
bool IsCorrect(string s)
{
    string[] split = s.split(':');
    int number1, number2;
    if (split.Length == 2 && split[0].Length == 5 && split[1].Length == 5)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(split[0], out number1) && int.TryParse(split[1], out number2) && number1 <= number2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With regex you can't make comparisons to see if a number is bigger than another number.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a good example of why you shouldn't try to do this. This is a regex that (nearly) does the same job.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad74e73f0350535d09c1

Raw file:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad74e73f0350535d09c1/raw/03ea835b0e7bf7ac3c5fb6f9c7e934b83fb09d95/gistfile1.txt

Except it's just for 3 digits. For 4, the program that generates these fails with an `OutOfMemoryException`. With `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` enabled. It went on until 5GB until it crashed. You don't want most of your app to be a Regex, right?

This is **not** a Regex's job.

Comment: Although not exactly a job for regex, there is a < 600 character expression which will cover validating one 5 digit number is less then another 5 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process because regex is a text parser and not analyzer. But with that said, Regex is perfect for validating that we have the 5:5 number pattern and this regex pattern will determine if we have that form factor \d\d\d\d\d:\d\d\d\d\d right. If that form factor is not found then a match fails and the whole validation fails. If it is valid, we can use regex/linq to parse out the numbers and then check for validity.

This code would be inside a method to do the check

```
var data = "00515:02151";
var pattern = @"
^               # starting from the beginning of the string...
(?=[\d:]{11})   # Is there is a string that is at least 11 characters long with only numbers and a ;, fail if not
(?=\d{5}:\d{5}) # Does it fall into our pattern? If not fail the match
((?<Values>[^:]+)(?::?)){2}  
";

// IgnorePatternWhitespace only allows us to comment the pattern, it does not affect the regex parsing
var result = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select (mt =>  mt.Groups["Values"].Captures
                                                .OfType<Capture>()
                                                .Select (cp => int.Parse(cp.Value)))
                  .FirstOrDefault();

// Two values at this point 515, 2151

bool valid = ((result != null) && (result.First () < result.Last ()));

Console.WriteLine (valid); // True
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Javascript this can work.

```
    var string = "00515:02152";

    string.replace(/(\d{5})\:(\d{5})/, function($1,$2,$3){ 
         return (parseInt($2)<=parseInt($3))?$1:null;
    });
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/VdzF7/

Comment: anybody care to explain why they gave me a downvote? I understand it's not c#, but the OP asked for any intelligent regex solutions...